# How do i get a value from sharedpreference when i don't know the key

Tags: android, dictionary, arraylist, sharedpreferences, key-value

How can i get a value from sharedpreference when i don't know the key?

Heres my code to save to sharedpreference:

```
String materia = data.getExtras().getString("materia");
                String profesor = data.getExtras().getString("profesor");
                String color = data.getExtras().getString("color");
                SharedPreferences saveMateria = getSharedPreferences(
                        tabChangedto, MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = saveMateria.edit();
                editor.putString(materia, materia);
                editor.putString(profesor, profesor);
                editor.putString("color", color);
                editor.commit();
```

I tried this:

```
        ArrayList<MateriaComplex> array = new ArrayList<MateriaComplex>();
        pref = getSharedPreferences(tabChangedto, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String, ?> keys = pref.getAll();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()) {
            /*
             * 
             * Here i want to extract the color value,materia value, profesor value.
             * But i don't know how, because the key has the name of the value, to avoid replacing it.
             * 
             */
        }
```

Comment: Have you considered [another storage option](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)? SharedPreferences are intended for key-value pairs, and it sounds like that doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: editor.putString("keys", profesor + "," + saveMateria);

Comment: @Tanis.7x Yes, i was wrong. Now i'm using sqlite databases. and my needs now are covered. :-)

Comment: @Triode I've changed to use databases. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SharedPreferences` in a way where you dont know the key then you are using `SharedPreferences` wrong.

you should probably look into using a SQL database to store what you want